# Resume of a kafka consumer not working in multiple binder scenario

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a requirement to pause the Kafka consumer and after a fixed interval it should resume .Pausing of kafka consumer is working as expected but issue is with Resume of Consumer . ListenerContainerIdleEvent is not being triggered after a fixed time interval in multiple binder scenario . Same code working if only configured for single binder .

Version  : 
Greenwich.SR1

Pause Implementation Code:

```
private void pauseConsumer(ErrorMessage message)
      {
        Message<?> failedMessage = message.getOriginalMessage();
        Consumer consumer (Consumer)failedMessage.getHeaders().get("kafka_consumer");
        consumer.pause(consumer.assignment());
      }
```

Resume Implementation code:

```
@Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerIdleEvent> idleListener() {
        return event -> {
            System.out.println(event + " paused:" + event.getConsumer().paused());
            if (event.getConsumer().paused().size() > 0) {
                event.getConsumer().resume(event.getConsumer().paused());
            }
        };
    }
```

application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 7778
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        kafka_binder:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream: 
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        input:  
          destination: EMPLOYEE-TOPIC-R1-P1
          binder: kafka_binder
          contentType: application/json
          group: so51247113
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of it since framework provides endpoint for controlling the lifecycle of each binding including pause/resume. Please reference to [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_visualization_and_control) section of the user guide. Basically you can invoke pause/resume via REST call

```
curl -d '{"state":"PAUSED"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://<host>:<port>/actuator/bindings/myBindingName
curl -d '{"state":"RESUMED"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://<host>:<port>/actuator/bindings/myBindingName
```

Comment: Yes, he can use those endpoints, but he needs a trigger for the resume; I have no problems getting an idle event when using named binders; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems receiving idle events when using a named binder...

```
spring.cloud.stream.binders.mykafka.type=kafka

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=mykafka
```

and

```java
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void foo(String in) {    
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void events(KafkaEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
```

and

```
ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=30.017s, listenerId=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[input-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[input-0]]
ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=60.037s, listenerId=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[input-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[input-0]]
ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=90.056s, listenerId=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[input-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[input-0]]
ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=120.072s, listenerId=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[input-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[input-0]]
ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=150.091s, listenerId=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b214b94.container-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[input-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[input-0]]
```